# Comparing two samples with pre and post each

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons

I gave an intervention to a Spanish speaking group and an English speaking group. I gave each group a pre (Spanish n=70, English n=35) and post (Spanish n=65, English n=32) knowledge survey. I want to see if there was a significant difference between the change in scores between the different language speakers, e.g., did the Spanish speakers demonstrate more improvement from the intervention or vice versa.

Is there a statistical test I can use to lump all this data in, or do I just need to do two separate t-tests and compare effect sizes? The data passes the assumptions for the t-test.

Comment: Difference-in-differences. Linear model with group effect and pre-post effect, and their interaction (product term). Test the hypothesis that the interaction is 0. Note: introduces added "assumption" of homoscedasticity... and also these "assumption tests" have more precision in the combined sample. Use robust standard errors for more valid inference.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is some loss to follow up. It's only a few, but with small sample sizes listwise deletion could be a problem.